# White screen because of do while loop

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, do-while

I'm pretty new to coding and I'm trying to code my first app for android studios using kotlin.

Whenever I try to start my app on an emulator (using following code), it just shows a white screen

```
    var useranswer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editNum1)
    var submitbutton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submitbutton)
    var questions = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.aufgaben)
    var highscore = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.punktestand)
    var timer = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timerrechts)
    
    var punkte: Int = 0
    
    submitbutton.setOnClickListener {
        
        object : CountDownTimer(60000,1000){
            override fun onFinish() {
                timer.text = "Zeit Abgelaufen!"
            }
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                timer.text = "Zeit: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000
            }
        }.start()


        if (useranswer.text.toString().length <= 0){
            submitbutton.setText("Submit")
            highscore.setText("Highscore: " +punkte)
            
            do {
                
                var rnds11 = (1..20).random()
                var rnds12 = (1..20).random()
                var sum1: Int
                sum1 = rnds11 + rnds12
                questions.text = "$rnds11 + $rnds12 = "


                submitbutton.setOnClickListener {
                    if(useranswer.text.toString().toInt() == sum1) {
                        punkte = punkte + 1
                        highscore.setText("Punktestand: " + punkte)


                    }
                }

            }while (useranswer.text.toString().toInt() == sum1)
        }

    }
}
```

the problem is because of the do while loop, whenever I try it without this loop it works perfectly fine but I want it to repeat if the user gives the correct answers.
Thank you so much for your help. I'm really in despair.

edit:
[Android Studio UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8imbA.jpg)

Comment: Could you edit your question adding your UI please? I'll try to replicate your problem

Comment: I think the problem is that waiting for a click on a button is not a blocking action; what happens in your example is the do..while loop runs once (unless it happens to end at the same number that is already in `useranswer` and then never again. If you move the whole checking part into the `setOnClickListener` and get rid of the loop, it will happen every time you click the button.

Comment: @AntonioLabra I added my UI to my question
----------
Joozd sounds good, I'll try it as you say, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're looking for something like this:

[image]

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Private Global Variables

    // Edit Text
    private lateinit var useranswer : EditText

    // Button
    private lateinit var submitbutton: Button

    // Text View
    private lateinit var questions: TextView
    private lateinit var highscore: TextView
    private lateinit var timer: TextView

    // Score
    var punkte = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        initComponents()

        submitbutton.setOnClickListener {
            if (useranswer.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                object : CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
                    override fun onFinish() {
                        timer.text = "Zeit Abgelaufen!"
                    }

                    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                        timer.text = "Zeit: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000
                        startToCount()  // Send this function when Tick happens
                    }
                }.start()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initComponents(){
        useranswer = findViewById(R.id.editNum1)
        submitbutton = findViewById(R.id.submitbutton)
        questions = findViewById(R.id.aufgaben)
        highscore = findViewById(R.id.punktestand)
        timer = findViewById(R.id.timerrechts)
    }
   
    private fun startToCount() {
        submitbutton.text = "Submit"
        highscore.text = "Highscore: $punkte"
        do {
            val rnds11 = (1..20).random()
            val rnds12 = (1..20).random()
            var sum1: Int

            sum1 = rnds11 + rnds12
            questions.text = "$rnds11 + $rnds12 = "


            if (useranswer.text.toString().toInt() == sum1) {
                punkte += 1
                highscore.text = "Punktestand: $punkte"
            }

        } while (useranswer.text.toString().toInt() == sum1)
    }
}
```

If I'm not wrong, you cannot use `.setOnClickListener` event inside a loop because it will break. I just make your variables "Global" and use your implementation when Ticker happens, so you're trying to do something when pass is countdown. Let me know if I'm right because looks interesting

**Ps. In the example. I put number 5 in the first field to make points haha**

Comment: first of all thank you for the fast answer^^ what I'm trying to do is a app where you have 60 seconds time to answer as many random math questions where two numbers from 1 to 20 are added. The user sees a question, has to give the answer and if he gives the right answer and presses the button, the highscore goes up by one and the random next math question will appear. I tried to use the do-while loop for this.  do{ mathquestion } while { answer to last question == sum of the two numbers}    
I hope I could describe my Idea and problem and I'm thankful for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
var useranswer = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editNum1)
var submitbutton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submitbutton)
var questions = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.aufgaben)
var highscore = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.punktestand)
var timer = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.timerrechts)
var rnds11:Int
var rnds12:Int
var sum1: Int
var countDown: CountDownTimer

var punkte: Int = 0

submitbutton.setOnClickListener {
    // stop the existing countDownTimer if it is not null. countDown.stop() or similar. then...
    if (useranswer.text.toString().toInt() == sum1) {
    punkte = punkte + 1
    highscore.setText("Punktestand: " + punkte)
    countDown : CountDownTimer(60000,1000){
        override fun onFinish() {
            timer.text = "Zeit Abgelaufen!"
        }
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            timer.text = "Zeit: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000
        }
    }.start()

        submitbutton.setText("Submit")
        highscore.setText("Highscore: " +punkte)
            
            rnds11 = (1..20).random()
            rnds12 = (1..20).random()
            sum1 = rnds11 + rnds12
            questions.text = "$rnds11 + $rnds12 = "
    } else {
          //Failed. Do your work
    }

}
}
```

You're creating a neverending loop in your listener. Listeners should not create themselves in a do-while loop **(unless intended cases)**, but rather they execute code and then leave. In my sample, when the user presses a button, you first check if the answer is correct. Then you reset the timer, update the scores, check if correct, then start the timer again with the new values.